# how to get 'an extra 9 hours'

Tags: comprehension

I had to read these sentences in an article.

> Most people need from 7 1/2 to 8 1/2 hours of sleep a night. You
>   cannot save hours of sleep the way you save money in the bank. If you
>   have only 5 hours of sleep for three nights, you don't need to sleep
>   an extra 9 hours on the  weekend.

I don't understand how to get 'an extra 9 hours'. Please explain it to me. I'm confused with the clause 'if you have only 5 hours of sleep for three nights'.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a math puzzle, and not about learning English

Comment: 8 hours-5 hours is 3 hours. 3 days x3 hours is 9 hours. Maths: close it.

Comment: @user3169 my OP is not a math puzzle. Not being a native, I don't understand the phrase '5 hours of sleep for three nights'. Instead of it, I want to use the phrase '5 hours of sleep each night for three nights'.

Comment: I think this question is about learning English, but that might not have been clear to the close voters based on the original form of the question.  @theinlwin Is there anything else you can add to make your question a little bit clearer so we can get it reopened?  What exactly is it that confuses you about this *if*-phrase?

Comment: @theinlwin I'm puzzled here. If you know that _5 hours of sleep for three nights_ has the same meaning as _5 hours of sleep each night for three nights,_  you _do_ understand it.

Answer (score 1):

See. 7 1/2 and 8.5 average to 8 hours.

So, if you sleep for 5 hours one day, you've lost 3 hours, right? (8 - 5 = 3)

If you do this for 3 days

, 3 * hours lost each day = total hours lost
3 * 3 = 9 
You get 9 hours. So, in order to compensate, you'll have to sleep extra 9 hours

But this is not how it works. 
This question doesn't actually belong here.

Comment: Thanks, Adam Karlson. In the 'if- clause', I'm confused with the phrase '5 hours of sleep for three nights'. Instead of the phrase, can I rewrite '5 hours of sleep each night for three nights'?

Comment: "5 hours of sleep for 3 nights" would be understood as 5 hours sleep each night by most people. "5 hours of sleep **over** 3 nights" would be understood as 5 hours sleep in total.